# Приоритет операций

Tags: c++, c

Не могу понять одну странность с приоритетом операторов в C++

```
void mass(int* der, int* a) 
{ 
cout << der << endl; //der = 0009D870
*der = 5; 
cout << der << endl; //der = 0009D870
*(der++) = 9; //тут проблема
cout << der << endl; //der = 0009D874 (инкрементируется также и при записи *++der)
} 
void main() 
{ 
int* der = new int[2]; 
der[0] = 3; 
der[1] = 3; 
mass(der, &der[1]); 
cout « der[0] « '\n' « der[1]; 
}
```

Если записать так: *(der++), то сначала происходит разыменование, а потом инкремент, несмотря на скобки. Значение элемента der[0] меняется на 5, а потом на 9.
Если записать так: *++der, то происходит сначала инкремент, потом разыменование, значение элемента массива der[0] меняется на 5, а der[1] на 9. 
Почему так происходит?

Comment: Потому что есть *префиксный* и *постфиксный* инкременты. Грубо и не совсем точно говоря, префиксный выполняется до, а постфиксный - после. Постфиксный возвращает то, что было до увеличения, а префиксный - что стало после него.

Comment: Но скобки же имеют больший приоритет, чем * и оба вида ++, разве нет?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Приоритет операций в языках С и С++ не имеет прямого отношения к порядку их выполнения. Приоритет операций описывает лишь группировку между операторами и операндами во внешне неоднозначных случаях, т.е. отвечает на вопрос о том, какой оператор относится к какому оператору.

(Формально в С и С++ нет никакого "приоритета операций", а есть только грамматика, которая и задает такую группировку. Так называемый *приоритет операций* - это лишь упрощенный и более удобный способ запоминания этой группировки.)

Вы также наделяете термин *выполняется* некоей атомарностью, которой у него на самом нет. У каждого оператора, у каждого подвыражения в С и С++ обычно есть *результат* и потенциально есть *побочные эффекты*. Вычисление результата оператора (value computation) - это одна часть процесса выполнения оператора, а материализация его побочных эффектов - это другая часть процесса его выполнения. Эти части выполняются в общем случае *независимо* друг от друга, в совершено разные моменты времени. То есть выполнение оператора в полном объеме может быть "размазано" по всему процессу вычисления полного выражения.

> Если записать так: *(der++), то сначала происходит разыменование, а потом инкремент, несмотря на скобки.

Здесь написана какая-то ерунда. Никакого "сначала происходит разыменование" тут нет и быть не может.

Из-за скобок никакой внешней неоднозначности тут нет: `++` относится к `der`, а `*` относится к результату `++`. Сначала вычисляется именно результат `++`. Так как это *постфиксный* `++`, его результатом должно быть *старое* значение `der`. Что вы и наблюдаете.

И совершенно не важно, произошло ли уже изменение значения переменной `der` в момент применения оператора `*`. Может произошло, а может нет. Главное, что `++` в качестве результата вернул *старое* значение и именно *старое* значение попало на вход оператору `*`. Это все, что вас должно беспокоить: `*` применяется к *старому* значению `der`. Всякие "сначала" и "потом" вас беспокоить не должны вообще.

Скобки тут ни на что не влияют. Их можно убрать и тогда для правильного понимания внешне неоднозначного выражения придется применить приоритеты. Так как постфиксные операторы всегда обладают бОльшим приоритетом, чем префиксные, выражение `*der++` разбирается как `*(der++)`.

> Если записать так: *++der, то происходит сначала инкремент, потом разыменование

В этом выражении неоднозначности нет и приоритеты никакой роли не играют вообще. `++` относится к `der`, а `*` применен к результату `++`.

Опять же, важно тут не то, что выполняется первым, а что вторым, а только то, что результат префиксного `++` - это *новое* значение `der`. То есть `*` должен применяться к увеличенному на 1 значению `der`.

Здесь, кстати, языки С и С++ формально ведут себя по-разному. Язык С++ гарантирует, что когда оператор `*` получает на вход увеличенное значение `der`, сама переменная `der` тоже уже получила новое значение. А вот язык С такого не гарантирует: оператор `*` тоже получает на вход увеличенное значение `der`, но вот было ли к этому моменту уже выполнена модификация самой перменной `der` - не оговаривается.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a[3]{};
int* der = a;  //der содержит адрес первого элемента массива
int* p = der++;
```

указатель `p` тоже содержит  адрес первого элемента, но  `der` уже(сразу после выражения) указывает на второй элемент

```
int* q = ++p;
```

`q` указывает на второй элемент, т.е. `q == der` , так что тут скобки роли не играют, дело в результате постфиксного и префиксного инкремента